# Why was E4X deprecated and removed from some browsers?

Tags: xml, firefox, e4x

Why was E4X deprecated and removed from some browsers?

> Warning: E4X is obselete. It's been disabled by default for chrome in
>   Firefox 17, and completely removed in Firefox 21. Use
>   DOMParser/DOMSerializer or a non-native JXON algorithm instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/E4X/Processing_XML_with_E4X

Comment: `for each…in` will probably never be removed so your quote is not completely true.

Comment: How does the `for each in` loop relate to E4X?

Comment: Because it's part of ECMA-357?

Comment: `for each` was going to be adapted in ECMAScript 4, but instead they added `for... of` statement in ES6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was deprecated and removed from the only browser that ever supported it because it was a poorly implemented language feature that was causing all sorts of problems.

> As Brendan said somewhere "E4X is crazyland", and FF's implementation of E4X deviates from the spec in ways that are not written down anywhere.
>
> — Mark S. Miller
>
> The only way for it to come back would be via a new edition of ECMA-357, which Adobe and Mozilla were going to work on. Until then, it's out.
>
> — Brendan Eich
>
> The idea behind it wasn't bad, but the way it was integrated into the language was. SpiderMonkey was the only JS engine that ever implemented it, and there were endless problems caused by that and severe complications of the engine's implementation required for this support.
>
> — Till Schneidereit

From [Bug 695577](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=695577)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The Flash Player and ActionScript3 implementation works flawlessly. It has been for years. It's a shame they don't implement it. If Adobe was able to share their code it might have made or make it easier.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts I love so much AS3, Shockwave and Flash